# Trying to pass multi-dimensional array to view with Codeigniter?

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

Simple stuff but my brain is blocked up and I can't work it out. Here's what builds the array in the controller:

```
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
  $slugs[] = $row->slug;
}

$data['slugs'] = $slugs;
print_r($data['slugs']); //returns array fine
```

Get view:

```
$this->load->view('pickcasino', $data);
```

This doesn't work in the view:

```
print_r($slugs);
```

How do I get it to work?

Comment: is it not `print_r($data['slugs']);` in the view ?

Comment: it does not matter it should print anyways

Comment: What does `var_dump($slugs);` output?

Comment: @Shomz that outputs NULL

Comment: That's really weird, are you sure you're not modifying the `$data` somewhere in the controller or `$slugs` somewhere in the view?

Comment: @Shomz thanks friend, I modified $data a bit further up. I find it bizarre that adding indexes to the end of the array messed it up.

Comment: Bizarre indeed - I've never encountered such a thing... but I'm glad you got it working, cheers! :)

Answer (score -1):

can you please check the `$this->load->view('pickcasino',$data);`  may be there is problem in load the view